# View at given print size

Tags: lightroom, printing, resolution

What is a good way of viewing an image at the same physical scale as a 
given print size?

E.g. say I want to print an image at 40x60cm. How do I (most easily) display the image so that 1cm on my screen equates to 1 cm on print?

Is there a way to do that in Lightroom (Classic CC)?

Answer (score 1):

Measure your screen.  We will just use the horizontal dimensions.  Say it's 20 inches.

You want to make a 40x60 image.  Long dimension of the print is 60 inches.  So you want to magnify it by 60/20  or 300%

This assumes that 100% = full screen.  Some software decrees that 100% means one campera pixel = 1 screen pixel.  I think Photoshop and Lightroom both do this.

So instead:  Click "fit to screen"  Now the magnification will show up somewhere. THIS is the number you would multiply by 3.

Blowup ratio of screen = screen width in pixels/image width in pixels.  This will be under 100%

B=Sw/Iw

Print ratio blowup = Printwidth / Screenwidth.

Lets do a walk through:

Load an image that is 4000 x 6000 pixels.  My monitor is only 1500 pixels wide, so that even when I say "full screen" the magnification is 25% (1500/6000)

But my monitor is 20 inches wide.  My print is 60 inches wide.  So 60/20 = 3.

So if I set my screen to 75% I will see 1 cm of screen = 1 cm of print.

Note:  Most of the time as images get bigger they are viewed from further away.  An 8x10 printed a 150 dpi normally will have invisible dots.  At 300dpi you need a hand lens.  This is one reason why office laser printers are 300 dpi for normal work.

So do you need more pixels to print it at 40 x 60?  Not really.  The 40 x 60 will likely be viewed from 5-10 feet away.  You can use bigger dots.

There are some exceptions to this:

A:  If you have a mural that people are going to view from a distance, AND get close to to look at details, then the whole image has to be done at a size for the closer viewing distance.  Murals in stairwells get this kind of scrutiny.

B:  A photo that you are going to turn into a jigsaw puzzle falls into this category.  You want each piece to have a sharp image when viewed from 7 inches away.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I am still hoping that a more convenient solution exists.